# android - How to disable auto brightness mode from API 4?

Tags: android, api, brightness

I can disable the auto brightness starting from api level 8.
What about older versions? 
How can I disable auto brightness mode from API 4?

Answer (score 0):

As per Google [android dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) only 0.3% device are on API level 4. Infect only 3.5% devices are below API level 7. So I guess you don't have to worry about API level 4 or for that matter anything below API level 8 is bit waste of time...

[image: Android Dashboard]

Comment: I'd like to encourage people to use old phones plus, 0.3% considering that there's 500 million android devices out there, is a big number.

Comment: Thanks to Auto Bright: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geekyouup.android.autobright
Source available: http://autobright.googlecode.com

    String SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE = "screen_brightness_mode";
    int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL = 0;
    int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC = 1; 
    
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL); 
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC); 
User permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE = "screen_brightness_mode";
private static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL = 0;
private static final int SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC = 1; 

Settings.System.putInt(resolver, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, mode); 
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, lev);
```